# How to access mysql dabasase on lan using java

Tags: java, mysql, lan

I have a a PC whose IP address is 192.168.0.101 and mysql port is 4000. When i try to connect to connect to it, it works fine but when i use another PC on the the same LAN whose IP address is 192.168.0.107, i keep on getting this exception:

```
Communication link failure due to underlying exception:
**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION**

java.net.ConnectionException
MESSAGE: connection timed out......
```

I have read so many posts like [How to make mySQL database at my local accessible from different machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701363/how-to-make-mysql-database-at-my-local-accessible-from-different-machines) 
but cant find my.cnf file. I also went through this [Connecting to MySQL Database over server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824797/connecting-to-mysql-database-over-server) but still things are not working.
All the computers on the lan are windows 7 x86.
Please help me sort out this. Regards...

Comment: maybe a firewall issue

Comment: Most likely it isn't even going over the network when it accesses MySQL the same machine.

Comment: you can ping ip 192.168.0.107, if it time out, you should contact to system team to config it

Comment: are you on DHCP? Meaning, a second box at `.107` ... probably a dumb question as it wouldn't be the one with the open socket

Comment: @ScaryWombat, how about the firewall thing? how do i go about it?

Comment: Enter the command `netstat -nat|grep 4000` on the MySQL server to see if MySQL is listening on that port and what the bind address is.  If it's not `0.0.0.0` then you need to change the `bind-address` parameter to it's listening for remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

Look this page for example
[java Connect](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)