# can I use mysql databases on a machine that mysql is not installed?

Tags: c++, mysql

Hello everyone I have mysql on my computer I installed it and installed the service successfully, I do some database using mysql now

the only question: can I run my c++ application that uses mysql databases on a computer where mysql is not installed??

my os is windows 7 x64;
any help is highly appreciated thank you for answering even after voting down.
I searched too much but in vain.

Comment: You mean like [connecting the database over network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824797/connecting-to-mysql-database-over-server)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for this useful link

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you first. can I copy my C++ executable and mysql db to a machine where mysql is not installed and be able to connect them?

Comment: You don't need to have the mysql server on your local machine, but can access a mysql server on another machine over the network.

Comment: You do need mysql client libraries installed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ consider I uninstall mysql server but I have my c++ executable and database on my local machine I want to connect these databases on this same local machine

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Excuse me for disturbing you

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you

Comment: @Syfu_H You  need to have a mysql server somewhere, a database is more than just a file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok perfect! now I understand that mysql databases cannot be accessed without my server. right?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  you mean that mysql databases cannot be accessed without my server right?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I said nothing about the server. What part of "you need mysql client libraries" you're not sure about?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes it's a bit complicated

Comment: What's complicated about needing mysql client libraries?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik believe me I just want to take take my c++ application with my mysql database then I run it on other machine. I don't know what client libraries

Comment: I explained: mysql client libraries. If you don't understand that mysql has a separate server component and a separate client library component, looks like you have some more learning to do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you very much. at last can you recommend a useful book about c++ and mysql